# Can we switch to using authenticated access to MongoDB with no downtime?

Tags: mongodb, authentication

We currently have a fairly complex Mongo environment with multiple query routers and data servers in different AWS regions using sharding and replication so that data will be initially written to a master shard in a local data server and then replicated to all regions.

When we first set this up we didn't add any security to the Mongo infrastructure and are using unauthenticated access for read and write.  We now need to enable authentication so that the platform components that are writing data can use a single identity for write and read, and our system administrators can use their own user accounts for admin functionality.

The question is whether and how we can switch to using authentication without taking any downtime in the backend.  We can change connection strings on the fly in the components that read and write to the DB, and can roll components in and out of load-balancers if we do need a restart.  The concern is on the Mongo side.

- Can we enable authentication without having to restart?
- Can we continue to allow open access from an anonymous user after enabling authentication (to allow backward compatibility while we update the connection strings)?

  - If not, can we change the query strings before we enable authentication and have Mongo accept the connection requests even though it isn't authenticating?
- Can we add authorization to our DBs and Collections after the fact?
- Will there be any risk to replication as we go through this process?  We have a couple of TB of data and if things get out of sync it's very difficult to force a resync.

I'm sure I'm missing some things, so any thoughts here will be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Ian

Comment: Can you tell us which MongoDB version your are ON? This can be done from 3.4

Comment: Sorry, should have included that.  We're on 3.2.18.  Can't upgrade to 3.4+ yet because we have some attribute names that are not compatible with 3.4.

Comment: Unfortunately it's only starting Mongo 3.4 that you can enable auth with no downtime.  Here is the documentation on how to https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enforce-keyfile-access-control-in-existing-sharded-cluster-no-downtime/